# command is working fine inside the docker container but not working in dockerfile when building image

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, devops, akamai

dockerfile code

```
 FROM ubuntu:20.04
 RUN  wget https://dl.google.com/go/go1.21.0.linux-amd64.tar.gz && \
      tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.21.0.linux-amd64.tar.gz && \
      export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin && \
      go version
 COPY akamai-v1.5.6-linux386 .
 RUN  chmod +x akamai-v1.5.6-linux386 && \
      mv akamai-v1.5.6-linux386 /usr/local/bin/akamai && \
      apt-get update
 RUN apt-get update && akamai install purge -y 
 EXPOSE 22
 CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

i am installing the akamai cli and akamai purge package.
i am getting following error-

```
=> ERROR [9/9] RUN apt-get update && akamai install purge -y                                                                                   85.0s
------                                                                                                                                                
 > [9/9] RUN apt-get update && akamai install purge -y:                                                                                               
0.655 Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                                                
0.865 Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                          
1.133 Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]                                                                         
2.375 Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                                                                
2.530 Fetched 114 kB in 2s (51.0 kB/s)
2.530 Reading package lists...
84.86  ERROR[0081] Package Is Not Available. Supported Packages Can Be Found Here: Https://Techdocs.Akamai.Com/Home/Page/Products-Tools-A-Z command=install
84.86  ERROR[0081] INSTALL ERROR: Package is not available. Supported packages can be found here: https://techdocs.akamai.com/home/page/products-tools-a-z command=install
84.86 Package is not available. Supported packages can be found here: https://techdocs.akamai.com/home/page/products-tools-a-z
------
Dockerfile:163

 161 |     # ENV PATH=/usr/local/bin/akamai:$PATH
 162 |     # RUN echo $PATH
 163 | >>> RUN apt-get update && akamai install purge -y 
 164 |     
 165 |     EXPOSE 22

ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update && akamai install purge -y" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

i am getting error on akamai install purge command. But same command is working if i comment it in dockerfile and use inside the container.
error is showing that package is not available but when i checked package is available at given link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to have `akamai purge` running on an Ubuntu Docker image.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM golang:alpine3.17 as builder

RUN apk add --no-cache $(apk search --no-cache | grep -q ^upx && echo -n upx) git \
  && git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/akamai/cli-purge \
  && cd cli-purge \
  && go mod tidy \
  && go build -o /akamai-purge -ldflags="-s -w" \
  && upx -3 -o/akamai-purge.upx /akamai-purge

RUN apk add --no-cache $(apk search --no-cache | grep -q ^upx && echo -n upx) git \
  && git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/akamai/cli \
  && cd cli \
  && go mod tidy \
  && go build -o /akamai -ldflags="-s -w" cli/main.go \
  && upx -3 -o/akamai.upx /akamai 

FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV AKAMAI_CLI_HOME=/cli

RUN mkdir -p \
        $AKAMAI_CLI_HOME/.akamai-cli/src/cli-purge/bin \
        $AKAMAI_CLI_HOME/.akamai-cli/logs
    
COPY --from=builder /akamai-purge.upx $AKAMAI_CLI_HOME/.akamai-cli/src/cli-purge/bin/akamai-purge
COPY --from=builder /go/cli-purge/cli.json $AKAMAI_CLI_HOME/.akamai-cli/src/cli-purge/cli.json

COPY --from=builder /akamai.upx /bin/akamai

COPY config $AKAMAI_CLI_HOME/.akamai-cli/config 

RUN chmod -R a+rwx ${AKAMAI_CLI_HOME}
```

Adding a configuration file will prevent you from being prompted about automatic upgrades when you first run `akamai`. This is copied across in the second stage of the build.

`config`

```
[cli]
cache-path         = /cli/.akamai-cli/cache
config-version     = 1.1
last-upgrade-check = ignore
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @datawookie it worked for me. Where you find that code please share it, i want to understand each command meaning. 

Still i am eager to know why akamai install purge is failing in dockerfile.

Comment: Glad that it helped! I put this together myself after looking at the code here: https://github.com/akamai/akamai-docker/tree/master/dockerfiles.

Comment: could you able to find why `akamai install purge` command is not working in dockerfile and working in container?

Comment: From what I recall, `akamai install purge` launched an interactive CLI application and it was difficult to fill in the required responses from the `Dockerfile`. I tried to use `expect` but even that was not successful. In the end though, I think that this approach (installing the CLI and the purge command separately) is more robust anyway. One of the key elements to this was installing a `config` file which turned off automating upgrades (this was one of the interactive options when you first run the CLI client).

Comment: But it is asking for (Y/N) only when i run command inside container - 

`harisingh@harisingh-shekhawat:~/poc/akamai$ sudo docker exec -it 6b18c9 /bin/bash 
root@6b18c92bb323:/# akamai install purge

? Akamai CLI can auto-update itself, would you like to enable daily checks? [Y/n]:  No
Attempting to fetch command from https://github.com/akamai/cli-purge.git... [OK]
Installing... [WARN]
unable to locate runtime: go. Please verify if the executable is included in your PATH
? Binary command(s) found, would you like to download and install it? Yes
Downloading binary... [OK]
`

Comment: But you don't need to install it again in the container: it's already there. Use the `Dockerfile` and `config` from my answer. Launch a container. Then run `akamai`. You'll see that `purge` is listed under the "Installed Commands". Then try `akamai purge`. You should see the usage information.